# Trying to manage Excel with vb.net but i recived "Cannot convert COM object from type..."

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm using the **"Microsoft.Office.Interop"** library to create an excel file. Have office 365 and imported this dll to my vb proyect: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\**Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll**"

So, i had this error:

> Cannot convert COM object from type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. An operation error occurred because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' generated the following error: Item not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND)).

**This is the code where i use the library:**

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Fexcel
    Public Sub importarExcel()
        Dim app As Excel.Application
        Dim libro As Excel._Workbook
        Dim hoja As Excel._Worksheet

        app = New Excel.Application
        libro = app.Workbooks.Add
        hoja = app.Worksheets(1)
        Dim direccion As String
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is "caused" for this line:
`libro = app.Workbooks.Add`

I quited the reference to the "Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" and added this: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\**Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll**"" (The change is that is the office14 folder) and **It didn't work**.

I made a new proyect and put the same code and added the reference to "Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" and... **It worked.** Here's the code of this new proyect:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim app As Excel.Application
        Dim libro As Excel._Workbook
        Dim hoja As Excel._Worksheet

        app = New Excel.Application
        libro = app.Workbooks.Add
        hoja = app.Worksheets(1)
        Dim direccion As String
    End Sub
End Class
```

**I still need to fix the error of my main proyect** and i don't know why it happens.

I looked for the error and a something they said to do is look for the registry of the error code to see if you have another version of office installed, i did not have other version of office. (I don't wanna reinstall msOffice, because i don't think it'll work, tell me if i'm wrong)

I think this error is caused in my main proyect; in importations, i don't think it's a thing of visual studio 2010 or office or the registry, but if you think you have a solution, tell it to me, please.

---

**Edit:**
I've actived the strict mode for my proyect (and had 243 errors). Now i have initialized the Excel objects how they should.

```
`
Dim app As Excel.Application
Dim libro As Excel.Worksheet
Dim hojaCompr As Excel.Worksheet
Dim hojaVent As Excel.Worksheet
Dim hojaGen As Excel.Worksheet
app = New Excel.Application

Dim direccion As String

libro = CType(app.Workbooks.Add, Excel.Workbook)
```

**The error was caused for** trying to define an workbook object without a CType() function to convert from the type Excel.applicationClass to a Excel.Workbook type.

**Thank you for helping!!**

Comment: The error is actually occurring at `app = New Excel.Application`. Try defining app as type `Excel._Application` (note the underscore) and also change `app = New Excel.Application`to `app = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel._Application)`.  `Excel._Application` is the real interface; the `Excel.Application` interface inherits from it and includes a reference to `Excel.ApplicationClass`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I defined the objects i was going to use as "`Object`", changed "`app = New Excel.Application`" and that's it.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Dim app As Object
Dim libro As Object
Dim hoja As Object

'Start a new workbook in Excel    
app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
libro = app.Workbooks.Add

hoja = libro.Worksheets(1)

libro.SaveAs("C:\Users\Ricardo\Documents\book.xlsx")' I will use an getSaveFilename, not this
app.Quit()
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Object will not have the properties and methods available from the Excel objects. You will be constantly casting by Dim these as Object.

Comment: For me, the methods and properties, using these objects, worked. The only problem is that as they are defined as objects, visual studio doesn't show me their methods (But i already ended using the excel library)

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: From the docs When you know the specific class at compile time, you should declare the object variable to be of that class. This is called early binding. Early binding improves performance and guarantees your code access to all the methods and properties of the specific class.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/object-variable-declaration

Comment: Ok, thank you. It now works with the strict mode. (I had 243 errors when i changed it. lol) And i defined the excel objects as `Excel.Application`, `Excel.Workbook` and `Excel.Worksheet`.